# Check if date is in required format or not using shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have a tab delimited file which is having 2nd, 3rd, 12th & 13th columns as date.
I want to make sure that those dates are in this format or not - mm/dd/yyyy, if they are not in this format, I want to stop the process and exit with 1. I was able to find a way to do that but in that first I have to pass each date from the column to a function, instead of doing that I would prefer doing it using awk command.

Similarly other columns in the files are of character data type and their max length needs to be 40. So, I have to check if they are more than of that length then also process should stop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [I see](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12606883/tech-fukrey) you've been a member of this forum for a year and a half and have asked 5 previous questions so you should already know this by now but - please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output and show your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you with that. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: I would use a language that has a proper date date type available to do the validation. Shell or awk can verify that your string has the appropriate number of digits and `/`s, in the correct order, but it becomes tricker. Is `13/0/2021` a valid date? `03/30/2021` is but `02/30/2021` is not, etc.

Comment: @chepner good point. GNU awk has `mktime()` but it'll try to figure out what you meant rather than discarding an invalid date, e.g. given `mktime("2021 02 30 0 0 0")` it'll treat that invalid date as if you wrote `mktime("2021 03 02 0 0 0")`, so the way to validate a date is to do `date="2021 02 30"; secs=mktime(date" 0 0 0"); if ( date == strftime("%F",secs) ) it was valid; else it wasnt`, i.e. convert the date to epoch seconds first, then convert the epoch seconds to a date, and if the resulting date equals the original date then it was a valid date.

Comment: Is `03/30/2021` really a valid date?  Perhaps `30/03/2021` is valid, and `03/30/2021` is not.  Localization is a non-trivial issue!

Answer (score 1):

As is indicated by [chepner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301453/check-if-date-is-in-required-format-or-not-using-shell-script#comment120714170_68301453), it is important to make use of a language that can recognize date's and validate if it is a valid date. If you want to make use of a shell-script you can do that in bash by using `date`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a array; do
  for i in 2 3 11 12; do date -d "${array[i-1]}" > /dev/null || exit 1; done
done < "$1"
```

However, if you have to process large files, this is not very practical as it requires many calls to an extra executable. GNU awk has time-processing capabilities. Validating a correct time, is a bit more tricky though as is indicated by [Ed Morton 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301453/check-if-date-is-in-required-format-or-not-using-shell-script#comment120715083_68301453). The function `mktime` treats dates additively:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
         print strftime(mktime("2000 01 01 0 0 0"),"%F")
         print strftime(mktime("2000 01 32 0 0 0"),"%F")
         print strftime(mktime("2000 01 -1 0 0 0"),"%F")
         print strftime(mktime("2000 13 01 0 0 0"),"%F")
       }'
2000-01-01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2000-02-01                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
1999-12-30                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
2001-01-01
```

So to validate your date, you have to check if the input format equals the output format:

```
$ awk 'function cvt_time(d) {
           return strftime( "%d/%m/%Y", mktime(substr(d,7,4)" "substr(d,4,2)" "substr(d,1,2)" 0 0 0") )
       }
       BEGIN{FS="\t"}
       ($2  != cvt_time($2) ) { exit 1 }
       ($3  != cvt_time($3) ) { exit 1 }
       ($12 != cvt_time($12)) { exit 1 }
       ($13 != cvt_time($13)) { exit 1 }' file
```